# Youtube Iframe: Duration is not visible in mobile resolution

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, iframe, youtube

Youtube Iframe video's duration (Current time/Total time) is not visible in **portrait mode of mobile resolution**.

I am embedding it as below.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/video_id" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Is there a way to make it visible in youtube video iframe?

Comment: Can you discard if css styles from your page *are* hiding those values, by any chance?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thanks for the suggestion. I have set width:120% from 100% in css style. Now it is showing these value.

Comment: Well done. I've posted an answer. Feel free to improve it if need it. Thank you

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I got timings by changing the width to 120%, but not able to show iframe content in center. While debugging I got to know that video tag which is getting generated inside iframe tag is having an inline style with left:70px; which causes the issue. But not able to change this inline style through script. So the issue still persist.

Comment: I see. My suggestion is then to post your css styles here and probably someone else with more knowledge about css can override those inline styles - like, using `!important` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

After following [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119605/youtube-iframe-duration-is-not-visible-in-mobile-resolution?noredirect=1#comment129150529_73119605) and according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119605/youtube-iframe-duration-is-not-visible-in-mobile-resolution?noredirect=1#comment129170916_73119605), the problem was in the CSS styles of your page.

Quote:

> I have set width:120% from 100% in css style. Now it is showing those
> values.